# How can I change the style of Airwallex input and button

Tags: payment-gateway

We've integrated the Airwallex payment form into our React-based website using the DropIn method. Currently, we are seeking assistance to customize the styling of the input fields and the proceed button as we are facing limitations in applying styles directly. Can anyone provide guidance on how to achieve this?

I attempted to apply styles using the 'container inherit' approach, but I encountered difficulties and was not successful

[here is the visual of form](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzutv.png)

Comment: If you are talking about this, https://www.airwallex.com/docs/payments__drop-in-element: The demo they are linking to there shows that this component renders inside an iframe, and that iframe content is loaded from a different origin - which means, you have no access to its contents _at all_ from within the scope of your own page. You are limited to whatever config options they provide to influence the styling then.

Comment: Yep, talking about the same link you provided, well in that case we have no option to customize. Thanks for helping.